# How to display HTML Element that is hidden partially

Tags: html, css

I'm working on modifying a legacy application where I'm allowed to do only css changes but no html and javascript changes. There are some styling issues which I'm trying to resolve thru CSS and one of them is that the elements are getting hidden behind each other.

I tried setting the position attributes and the z-index attributes at different levels for the elements, but none of them seem to work. Here is a scaled down version of the layout of the application

Currently the yellow box is partially hidden under the pink box. The expectation here is that the yellow box is shown completely, overlapping on both the aqua and pink boxes. Any help to resolve this by modifying only the CSS and not touching anything inside the table element would greatly be helpful

```css
.mainTable {
  border: black 1px solid;
}

.aquaBox {
  border: green 1px solid;
  background: aqua;
  overflow: visible;
}

.yellowBox {
  border: black 1px solid;
  background: yellow;
}

.pinkBox {
  border: red 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table class='mainTable'>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='2' class='aquaBox' style=' width:100px; height: 100px;'>
        abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvw xyz
        <div class='yellowBox' style='width: 40px; top: 25px; height: 40px; margin-top:25px; margin-left:60px;  position:absolute; '>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='pinkBox' style='width: 100%; height: 200px;'>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `z-index: 1` to make this work, which promotes the element's stacking order and allows it to show on top of elements placed outside the stacking order.

```css
.yellowBox {
  …
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[image]

**Demo**

```css
.mainTable {
  border: black 1px solid;
}

.aquaBox {
  border: green 1px solid;
  background: aqua;
  overflow: visible;
}

.yellowBox {
  border: black 1px solid;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pinkBox {
  border: red 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<table class='mainTable'>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='2' class='aquaBox' style=' width:100px; height: 100px;'>
      abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvw xyz
      <div class='yellowBox' style='width: 40px; top: 25px; height: 40px; margin-top:25px; margin-left:60px;  position:absolute; '>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='pinkBox' style='width: 100%; height: 200px;'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, Had tried this along with position:fixed, and somehow was quite not getting it right. Will give this a try again. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the `z-index: 1;` on your `.yellowBox` class, I was able to get the desired layout.

`````````````````````````````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      .mainTable {
        border: black 1px solid;
      }

      .aquaBox {
        border: green 1px solid;
        background: aqua;
        overflow: visible;
      }

      .yellowBox {
        border: black 1px solid;
        background: yellow;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      .pinkBox {
        border: red 1px solid;
        position: relative;
        background: pink
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class='mainTable'>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' class='aquaBox' style=' width:100px; height: 100px;'>
          abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvw xyz
          <div class='yellowBox' style='width: 40px; top: 25px; height: 40px; margin-top:25px; margin-left:60px;  position:absolute; '>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='pinkBox' style='width: 100%; height: 200px;'>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```````````````````````````` Currently the yellow box is partially hidden under the pink box. The expectation here is that the yellow box is shown completely, overlapping on both the aqua and pink boxes. Any help to resolve this by modifying only the
CSS and not touching anything inside the table element would greatly be helpful
`````````````````````````````

Comment: Thanks Rowan for the solution. Will give this one a try. Cheers.